# In Spring, how do I redirect the user to a different domain, while preserving their session?

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-security

I’m using Spring and Spring Security 3.1.4.RELEASE.  I am logged in, with session established on one subdomain — https://main.mydomain.com/myapp but I would like to redirect the user to a different subdomain, e.g. https://second.mydomain.com/myapp but keep the user logged in.  How do I do that?  I don’t want the user to have to login a second time but I would like something secure .

I can upgrade Spring if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to **share application sessions**, you'd need two things (not really Spring related actually):

- the session cookie should be set on the shared domain `mydomain.com` and not on a subdomain `main.mydomain.com`
- sessions should be stored in a shared repository (such as redis)

This can be tricky, because those two applications now need to be in sync regarding what's stored in session. Serialization, change of implementation, etc can render this strategy useless.

If you're looking for **Single Sign On**, then you should take a look at the various SSO implementations out there.

Comment: We do have a session-sharing service across the applications so your first suggestion about setting the domain apporpriately in the cookie will probably be the easier solution to implement.  What litlte I have read about oauth2 tells me its more suited to resource access as opposed to SSO.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion - OAuth is about authorization, not authentication. Editing my answer.